# ValueError: Columns must be same length as key ---- Why is this happening?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df['location'] = df['Address'].apply(geocode)
df['point'] = df['location'].apply(lambda loc: tuple(loc.point) if loc else None)
df[['latitude', 'longitude', 'altitude']] = pd.DataFrame(df['point'].tolist(), index=df.index)
```

I have only one column called *address* but not sure why am I getting this error. Tried cleaning and checked running just with one record but the error persists. But all of a sudden for a few sets of data it worked fine. Help me understand Thanks

Comment: check `isinstance(df.columns, pd.MultiIndex)`

Comment: The outcome is False.... Could you help me understand how does this help me. I am new to python. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `tuple(loc.point)` always returns a tuple of len=3? After the second line, you can check by running `df[df.point.apply(len) != 3]` to find any culprit rows. Essentially, if you are trying to assign a dataframe with more than 3 columns (right hand side) to 3 columns (left hand side), you will get this error.